# How to achieve this in crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

How to do this in crystal report with sub-report

[image]

the image above is from excel and that's what im trying to achieve..and here's what i do in crystal report

[image]

and after i run it..the result is devastating..lol here's what it looks like[image]

the sub-report is just keep on repeating..lol how to fix this ? i already set the sub-report link id's..it's all good but the only problem is that its keep on repeating where what i want is to only show the sub-reports content if the id's is match..btw im using vb.net for the project

Comment: how many records will be present for single ID?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put it in the ***Details Section***. I suggest you put it in your ***Report Footer Section*** or ***Group Footer Section*** (based on which group you are summarizing). Putting it in the ***Details Section*** will repeat the ***Sub Report*** depending on how many records you show in that area.

Comment: hmmm..i'll try that mate :)

Comment: i did't change any of it..i just set the sub-report link id again (by means of again it just that i set the same id)..and now it works..why is that ? a bug ?

Comment: The _sub report_ is still in the _details section_? What are ur links?